# How to make a Employee-Company relation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to

I'm trying to create a jobs board on Ruby on Rails. I'm using devise to handle accounts, and I have a Employee(device user) and Company models.

In this challenge, when someone creates an account as employee, I have to check if the company domain already exists (the domain is extracted from the employee email), and if it doesn't, the employee must be redirected to a page for registering the company. Also, this first employee becomes the company's admin.

The problem is, how to do a proper relation between then? If I use a belongs_to relation with one another, it's impossible to create an Employee without an Company an vice-versa. And if I don't, there's no way to access some ids later to make the proper relations. To make matters worse, later I'll need to create an JobAd model for the job ads, which should belong to both company and employee. So, is there any way to implement this without the "Employee without an Company an vice-versa" problem?

This is my schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_02_23_032327) do

  create_table "applicants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_applicants_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_applicants_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "logo"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "cnpj"
    t.string "site"
    t.string "social_media"
    t.string "domain"
    t.integer "employee_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["employee_id"], name: "index_companies_on_employee_id"
  end

  create_table "companies_employees", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "employee_id", null: false
    t.integer "company_id", null: false
    t.index ["company_id", "employee_id"], name: "index_companies_employees_on_company_id_and_employee_id"
    t.index ["employee_id", "company_id"], name: "index_companies_employees_on_employee_id_and_company_id"
  end

  create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_employees_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_employees_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "job_ads", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "salary_range"
    t.integer "level"
    t.date "mandatory_requirements"
    t.integer "total_vacancy"
    t.integer "company_id", null: false
    t.integer "employee_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_job_ads_on_company_id"
    t.index ["employee_id"], name: "index_job_ads_on_employee_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "companies", "employees"
  add_foreign_key "job_ads", "companies"
  add_foreign_key "job_ads", "employees"
end
```

What I'm trying right now:

device's registration_controller.rb for employees

```
class Employees::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    domain = resource.email.split('@').last
    if domain_is_free?(domain)
      @employee.save
      redirect_to new_company_path
      flash[:notice] = "Não identificamos o domínio #{domain}, por favor registre-o"
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)
    if @employee.save
      sign_in(@employee)
      after_sign_up_path_for(@employee)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  protected

  def domain_is_free?(employee_mail)
    !Company.exists?(['domain LIKE ?', "%#{employee_mail.split('@').last}%"])
  end 

  def employee_params
    params.require(:employee)
        .permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :employee
    has_many :employees
    has_many :job_ads    
end
```

employee.rb

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  belongs_to :company, optional: true                  
        
end
```

The rspec test

```
    require 'rails_helper'

feature 'employee creates an account' do
  scenario 'and is the first to register a domain' do
    visit root_path
    click_on 'Employee registration'

    within('form') do
      fill_in 'Email', with: 'roger@jobs.com'
      fill_in 'Password', with: '123456'
      fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: '123456'
      click_on 'Sign up'
    end

    expect(current_path).to eq new_company_path
    expect(page).to have_content 'There is no company named jobs, please register it'  
    expect(page).to have_content 'Register Company'
  end
```

And finally the error message

```
Failure/Error:
   params.require(:company)
         .permit(:name, :logo, :address, :cnpj, :site, :social_media, :domain).merge(employee_id: current_employee.id)
 
 ActionController::ParameterMissing:
   param is missing or the value is empty: company
   Did you mean?  controller
                  action
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with the associations here, Try removing the `belongs_to :employee` from `company.rb` file.

So what belongs_to means is that one instance of model A belongs to one instance of model B. That means an instance of A cannot exist without an instance of B(for example Book cannot exist without an Author). check this [link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) for more!

Also as you want an employee to be admin of a company, add admin field in employee.rb as boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood all the things...

1. When you define a `belongs_to` relation you have to provide the foreign key to this table. In `employee.rb` you write `ruby belongs_to :company, optional: true` but don't add the `company_id` field to the `employees` table.

```rb
  create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_employees_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_employees_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

```rb
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  belongs_to :company, optional: true                  
        
end
```

Maybe you just need this `has_one` instead.

2. What if you just will use

```rb
@employee.create_company(company_params)
```

In this case you don't have to pass `employee_id` with params. But again you should add foreign key to Employees table or replace to `has_one :company` in `Employee` model.

3. You can try to create an `employee` and a `company` at the same time.

Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :company` to the `Employee` model, and in controller you can call something like this:

```rb
def create
  ...
   @employee.create(employee_params)
  ...
end

def employee_params
    params.require(:employee)
          .permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, company_attributes: [:name, :logo, :address, :cnpj, :site, :social_media, :domain])
end
```

But it also will work only if you add the `company_id` field to the Employee table. Anyway you can do the same vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I had a company_id in employee.rb, but I removed it because I was trying to make an employee with an empty company_id an add it later, but it seems too complicated. I'll try your sugestion, but it's possible to create an employee and a company in the same controller using nested attributes?